# Dynamic size of array in mongoose schema of mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema for an application

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const matchSchema= mongoose.Schema({

  match_id:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  NumOfPlayers :{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },    
  winners:{
    num: Number,
    rank1_amt : Number,
    rank2_amt : Number,
    rank3_amt : Number,
    rank4_amt : Number,
    rank5_amt : Number,
  },
  entry_Amt:{
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});
```

and this should look something like this in MongoDB

```
{
    match_id : 0000000
    NumOfPlayers : 20
    winners:{
        num:4
        rank1_amt : 100
        rank2_amt : 50
        rank3_amt : 25
        rank4_amt : 25
    }
    entry_amt : 10
}
```

i am making an application where no of winners can change according to `winners.num` i.e for a match there can be only 2 Ranks for another 10 Ranks. i want to have dynamic no of `ranks` under `winners` and how to set scheme for that  in mongoose.

Comment: Please explain dynamic number of ranks

Comment: dynamic no od ranks means in a match there can be only 2 winners i.e 1st and 2nd rank, while in some match there can be 5 winners i.e ranks 1-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `winners` an array like this

```
winners: [{rank: Number, amount: Number}]
```

Comment: Oh , That was so silly of me , well i am new to mongo, looks like i need to nest schemas